# python3: socket.gethostbyaddr(): "Unknown host" vs "Host name lookup failure"

Tags: python-3.x, dns, gethostbyaddr

I am using `socket.gethostbyaddr()` in python3 to resolve IP to hostname.

I need to distinguish between 3 cases:

```
1) success (IP resolved to hostname)
2) IP address has no DNS record
3) DNS server is temporarily unavailable
```

I am using simple function:

```
def host_lookup(addr):
    try:
        return socket.gethostbyaddr(addr)[0]
    except socket.herror:
        return None
```

and then I want to call this function from my main code:

```
res = host_lookup('45.82.153.76')

if "case 1":
    print('success')
else if "case 2":
    print('IP address has no DNS record')
else if "case 3":
    DNS server is temporarily unavailable
else:
    print('unknown error')
```

When I try `socket.gethostbyaddr()` in python console, I get different error codes in each case:

```
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('45.82.153.76')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host
```

and when I deliberatrely make DNS unreachable:

```
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('45.82.153.76')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.herror: [Errno 2] Host name lookup failure
```

So how can I differentiate between these cases in my code above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[socket.herror](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.herror) is a subclass of [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) that provides access to the numeric error code `errno`:

```
import socket

def host_lookup(addr):
    return socket.gethostbyaddr(addr)[0]

try:
    res = host_lookup("45.82.153.76")
    print('Success: {}'.format(res))
except socket.herror as e:
    if e.errno == 1:
        print('IP address has no DNS record')
    elif e.errno == 2:
        print('DNS server is temporarily unavailable')
    else:
        print('Unknown error')
```

Comment: Use `import errno` and the symbolic error codes instead of the numerical ones. Makes the code easier to read and more foolproof.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek - can you please show an example, how to use symbolic error codes instead of the numerical ones ?

Comment: `import errno; print errno.ENOENT == 2` will show `True`. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/errno.html or equivalent for the full list of available variables.

Comment: However, in this case, the error numbers are not the standard [errno](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html) system symbols but those of [h_errno](https://linux.die.net/man/3/h_errno). It's probably better to declare them yourself: `HOST_NOT_FOUND = 1; TRY_AGAIN = 2; NO_RECOVERY = 3;  NO_DATA = 4; NO_ADDRESS = NO_DATA`.